# Messaging.sendEmail - You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: apex, email, callout, send-email

I have a callout class to make a call to a web service, I would like to send an email when the callout fails:

```
String ret='';
try {
    ret = ApprovalService.CreateApprovalRequest(sessionId, obj.Name, obj.Description__c);
} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    ret = e.getMessage();

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'test@mail.com'};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

    mail.setSubject('Exception occurred when calling Metastorm interface for ' + obj.Name);

    mail.setPlainTextBody(e.getMessage());
    mail.setHtmlBody(e.getMessage());

    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
ApprovalService.Logout(sessionId);
```

When I call this code and the callout fails I get an error:

**You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out**

for the

```
ApprovalService.Logout(sessionId);
```

line.

But if I comment this line

```
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

I don't get the error, of course the email is also not sent also so I'm back to square one.

I don't understand why the sendEmail should request a commit or rollback, it's not supposed to be a DML operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email Message probably try to insert a Task or an EmailMessage object (Sorry can't remember exactly). Maybe just try to set `mail.SaveAsActivity = false;`. 
Otherwise, why don't you send your email after Logout function ?

```
String ret='';
Boolean calloutError = false;

try {
    ret = ApprovalService.CreateApprovalRequest(sessionId, obj.Name, obj.Description__c);
} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    ret = e.getMessage();
    calloutError = true;
}

ApprovalService.Logout(sessionId);
if (calloutError == true){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'test@mail.com'};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

    mail.setSubject('Exception occurred when calling Metastorm interface for ' + obj.Name);

    mail.setPlainTextBody(e.getMessage());
    mail.setHtmlBody(e.getMessage());

    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

Comment: setSaveAsActivity only applies if the recipient list is based on targetObjectId or targetObjectIds which was not the case here (see  [Email Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm#apex_Messaging_Email_setSaveAsActivity)).     The idea to avoid the Logout was the solution, I added a Boolean set to true in the catch and then only do the Logout if the Boolean is true.  Not sure about the consequences of not doing the Logout though

Comment: Just try to move sendEmail after Logout function as I proposed.